# Can GETH run quickly and be always up-to-date with an AWS c5 instance?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, nodes, aws

I've noticed that most people who are using AWS to run their ethereum node are using the i3 (or i3en) instance type for its high I/O performance with the attached SSD.

For my particular use case, I want to run some separate fairly computation-intensive processes on the same machine as my GETH node, so the c5 (or c5a) instance type would be better suited for that purpose. Would GETH run well on a c5 (or c5a) instance type with an attached gp2 EBS volume, or would that cause degradation in performance? (I would of course sync first on an i3, then move the data over to a c5 for production)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can run on c5.

[Amazon Managed Blockchain for Ethereum](https://aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/pricing/ethereum/) service offers several instance types, and `c5` is one of them. It has `c5.xlarge`, `c5.2xlarge` and `c5.4xlarge`.

I suggest also testing `m5` instances, as they provide faster memory access, which can help if the state you're accessing happen to be cached in memory by either Geth or LevelDB.